# java.lang.IllegalStateException: UserDetailsService is required. with custom provider

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I implemented a custom user details service interface so i can pass organizationId with username

```
public interface CustomUserDetailsService {

    UserDetails loadUserByUsernameAndOrganizationId(UUID organizationId, String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException;
}
```

and implemented it in a service class:

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl implements CustomUserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsernameAndOrganizationId(UUID organizationId, String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        //Method implementation

        return UserDetails;
    }
}
```

Then implemented a custom authentication token to allow sending organizationId:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationToken extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private UUID organizationId;

    public CustomAuthenticationToken(Object principal, Object credentials, UUID organizationId) {
        super(principal, credentials);
        this.organizationId = organizationId;
        super.setAuthenticated(false);
    }

    public CustomAuthenticationToken(Object principal, Object credentials, UUID organizationId, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(principal, credentials, authorities);
        this.organizationId = organizationId;
        super.setAuthenticated(true); // must use super, as we override
    }

    public UUID getOrganizationId() {
        return organizationId;
    }
}
```

And a custom authentication filter so i can extract organizationId from request and pass it to CustomAuthenticationToken class:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    public static final String SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_ORGANIZATION_KEY = "organizationId";

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {

        if (!request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Authentication method not supported: " + request.getMethod());
        }

        CustomAuthenticationToken authRequest = getAuthRequest(request);
        setDetails(request, authRequest);
        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
    }

    private CustomAuthenticationToken getAuthRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String username = obtainUsername(request);
        String password = obtainPassword(request);
        UUID organizationId = obtainOrganizationId(request);

        if (username == null) {
            username = "";
        }
        if (password == null) {
            password = "";
        }

        return new CustomAuthenticationToken(username, password, organizationId);
    }

    private UUID obtainOrganizationId(HttpServletRequest request) {
        UUID organizationId = null;
        String organizationIdStr = request.getParameter(SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_ORGANIZATION_KEY);
        if (organizationIdStr != null && !organizationIdStr.trim().isEmpty())
            organizationId = UUID.fromString(organizationIdStr);
        return organizationId;
    }

}
```

And in my custom provider i do next implementations:

```
@Component
public class CustomUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private ResourceServerTokenServices tokenServices;

    /**
     * The plaintext password used to perform PasswordEncoder#matches(CharSequence, String)} on when the user is not found to avoid SEC-2056.
     */
    private static final String USER_NOT_FOUND_PASSWORD = "userNotFoundPassword";

    /**
     * The password used to perform {@link PasswordEncoder#matches(CharSequence, String)} on when the user is not found to avoid SEC-2056. This is necessary, because some {@link PasswordEncoder}
     * implementations will short circuit if the password is not in a valid format.
     */
    private String userNotFoundEncodedPassword;

    @Override
    protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

        if (authentication.getCredentials() == null) {
            logger.debug("Authentication failed: no credentials provided");
            throw new BadCredentialsException(messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"));
        }

        String presentedPassword = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        if (!passwordEncoder.matches(presentedPassword, userDetails.getPassword())) {
            logger.debug("Authentication failed: password does not match stored value");
            throw new BadCredentialsException(messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doAfterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        Assert.notNull(this.userDetailsService, "A UserDetailsService must be set");
        this.userNotFoundEncodedPassword = this.passwordEncoder.encode(USER_NOT_FOUND_PASSWORD);
    }

    @Override // Note that we must cast the authentication token to our CustomAuthenticationToken.
    protected UserDetails retrieveUser(String username, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        CustomAuthenticationToken auth = (CustomAuthenticationToken) authentication;
        UserDetails loadedUser;

        try {
            loadedUser = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsernameAndOrganizationId(auth.getOrganizationId(), auth.getPrincipal().toString());
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException notFound) {
            if (authentication.getCredentials() != null) {
                String presentedPassword = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
                passwordEncoder.matches(presentedPassword, userNotFoundEncodedPassword);
            }
            throw notFound;
        } catch (Exception repositoryProblem) {
            throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException(repositoryProblem.getMessage(), repositoryProblem);
        }

        if (loadedUser == null) {
            throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException("UserDetailsService returned null, " + "which is an interface contract violation");
        }
        return loadedUser;
    }

}
```

And finally i used my provider inside my WebSecurityConfiguration which extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider authProvider;
    @Autowired
    private ServEngineBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }
}
```

Till now everything goes fine and great and no problems at all when i run my springboot application, but i got an error when i tried to call refresh token service **/oauth/token?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=MY_REFRESH_TOKEN_DENERATED_BEFORE**
and the error is:

```
o.s.s.o.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint  : Handling error: IllegalStateException, UserDetailsService is required.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: UserDetailsService is required.
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:464)
    at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper.loadUserDetails(UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper.java:68)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:175)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices.refreshAccessToken(DefaultTokenServices.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.refresh.RefreshTokenGranter.getAccessToken(RefreshTokenGranter.java:47)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.AbstractTokenGranter.grant(AbstractTokenGranter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.CompositeTokenGranter.grant(CompositeTokenGranter.java:38)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer$4.grant(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer.java:583)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(TokenEndpoint.java:132)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:798)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:64)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter.doFilter(OAuth2ClientContextFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:747)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

So now how i can pass my custom user details service with its custom load user method by organizationId and username so oauth2 refresh token service uses it instead of default spring userDetailsService which not in use any more by my application because it has only one method to load user by username

BTW i floowed this article to implement spring security extra login fields:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-extra-login-fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved by next implementation:

Implementing a CustomPreAuthProvider

```
@Component("preAuthProvider")
public class CustomPreAuthProvider extends PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationUserDetailsService<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> userService;

    public CustomPreAuthProvider() {
        super();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        super.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(userService);
    }
}
```

Then implemented a CustomPreAuthUserDetailsService which implemented AuthenticationUserDetailsService and inside override loadUserDetails method i called my custom method load user by organizationId and username.

```
@Service
public class CustomPreAuthUserDetailsService implements AuthenticationUserDetailsService<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomPreAuthUserDetailsService.class);

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserDetails(PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken token) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        logger.info("CustomPreAuthUserDetailsService.loadUserDetails(PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken token) called.");
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) token.getPrincipal();
        JwtUser jwtUser = (com.skios.ms.authentication.JwtUser) usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.getPrincipal();

        return userDetailsService.loadUserByUsernameAndOrganizationId(jwtUser.getOrganizationId(), jwtUser.getUsername());
    }
}
```

and finally adding this to AuthenticationManagerBuilder in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter configurer class:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("preAuthProvider")
private AuthenticationProvider preAuthProvider;

@Autowired
private CustomUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

@Override
@Autowired
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider).authenticationProvider(preAuthProvider);
}
```

And my problem finally solved and now i can regenerate a new access token using refresh token and load user by custom load method which accepts organizationId and username :)